# Android Java: Camera2 preview image is stretched

Tags: java, android, android-camera, android-camera2

I am currently making my android app with camera2 API. I am able to make images, save them, edit them and so on. But my camera is always stretched.

I am using the Samsung Galaxy Tab A and the Samsung Galaxy Note 8, so not 16:9 ratio.

First of all, I only take pictures in landscape mode.

My **textureView** is exactly the same size like my display. My preview should be better, because I use its size for saving the image also. But also if setting it to the same size like my display I get stretched images.

```
            //getting the ratio, correct setting of sizes
        if (verh == sechzehnzuneun) {
            newSize = new Size(2300, 1350);
        } else if (verh == sechzehnzuzehn) {
            newSize = new Size(2400, 1500);
        } else if (verh == note8) {
            newSize = new Size(2792, 1440);
        }
//also used for saving
        _imageDimension = newSize;

        //used for rotating the preview, otherwise i geht some strange portrait camera 
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
        RectF textureRectF = new RectF(0, 0, _textureView.getWidth(), _textureView.getHeight());
        RectF previewRectF = new RectF(0, 0, _imageDimension.getHeight(), _imageDimension.getWidth());
        float centerX = textureRectF.centerX();
        float centerY = textureRectF.centerY();
        if (rotation == Surface.ROTATION_90 || rotation == Surface.ROTATION_270) {
            previewRectF.offset(centerX - previewRectF.centerX(),
                    centerY - previewRectF.centerY());
            matrix.setRectToRect(textureRectF, previewRectF, Matrix.ScaleToFit.FILL);
            float scale = Math.max((float) width / _imageDimension.getWidth(),
                    (float) height / _imageDimension.getHeight());
            matrix.postScale(scale, scale, centerX, centerY);
            matrix.postRotate(90 * (rotation - 2), centerX, centerY);
        } else {
            //neu weg wenn nicht
            previewRectF.offset(centerX - previewRectF.centerX(), centerY - previewRectF.centerY());
            matrix.setRectToRect(textureRectF, previewRectF, Matrix.ScaleToFit.FILL);
            float scale = Math.max((float)height / _imageDimension.getHeight(), (float)width / _imageDimension.getWidth());
            matrix.postScale(scale, scale,centerX,centerY);
            matrix.postRotate(0, centerX, centerY);
        }
        _textureView.setTransform(matrix);
```

I am getting the if case of upper code.

But look (only looking in portrait at it, but there is no orientation change, always horizontal)

[image: But look (only looking in portrait at it, but there is no orientation change, always horizontal):]

Looking in landscape

[image: Looking in landscape]

Comment: Nobody can help? I found lots of post, but nothing is helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at the [AutoFitTextureView](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2basic/AutoFitTextureView.java) in the sample camera2 apps from Google?

There's no particular guarantee that the camera device supports exactly the display size of the device, and if it doesn't, a size close to the requested size is selected.  But that will likely not have the same aspect ratio.

You need to pick a size that the camera device actually supports, and then set your TextureView to a matching aspect ratio.

Comment: So the TextureView and the Preview should be at the same size? I have a Galaxy Tab A, which has a resolution 1920x1200, so if I want a 16:9 picture I vertically should black bars, but I don't know, why it still gets stretched.

Comment: @Damaro this accepted answer resolves your issue ? facing same issue in portrait mode with textureView